# Forest.GetCurrentForest() - possible Exceptions when called by local User

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2016

The code tries to get information about the available domains via `Forest.GetCurrentForest()`. When this code is run by a local user (no domain user), an exception is thrown. This excepetion differs from windows server 2008 (R2?) to windows server 2016.

On windows server 2008 a `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryOperationException` is throw but on windows server 2016 a `System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException` is thrown.

According to the Documentation, `GetCurrentForest()` can throw the `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryOperationException` exception.

What exceptions can really be thrown by `Forest.GetCurrentForest()`?

Comment: Now, I'm also stuck here to identify if we can use local user account to run this command! As per the documentation, it seems there is no luck! I'm also receiving `System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException -> The user name or password is incorrect.` followed by `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException -> The user name or password is incorrect.`!